# Improving loading speed of pages

Tags: php, performance, loading, soundcloud

I have been looking on different websites and I found that one of these websites have a insane loading speed and I don't know how they do it. Here's the website that I'm talking about [Sound Cloud](https://soundcloud.com/), can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this Google tool. It has a lot of great tips on speeding up your site.

[Google Insights](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

[Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro)

Comment: I'm sure this is great however I can't seem to use it when I'm using localhsot

Comment: added another link for best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Google Chrome** browser, then click **CTRL + SHIFT + I** to open the DevTool. Open the page contanining the code you want to investigate and in the "Network" tab look for what parts of code need more time to be loaded (or it gives you some kind of error).
For me this is the best way to start a deeper analysis.